# Firebase code 400 "message": "CONFIGURATION_NOT_FOUND"

Tags: javascript, html, css, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently trying to create a DB on Firebase and I am getting the following error:

```
{"error":{"code":400,"message":"CONFIGURATION_NOT_FOUND","errors":[{"message":"CONFIGURATION_NOT_FOUND","domain":"global","reason":"invalid"}]}}
```

I know this is sensible but my code for setting up the database is the following:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.3.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.3.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>

<script>
    // Your web app's Firebase configuration
    // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
    var firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "AIzaSyAI6HD2Fa35nSL3wqT1u98TgdykPoU1Vvc",
        authDomain: "todo-ca9f2.firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL: "https://todo-ca9f2-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/",
        projectId: "todo-ca9f2",
        storageBucket: "todo-ca9f2.appspot.com",
        messagingSenderId: "787961698428",
        appId: "1:787961698428:web:c2af07085cdd3c9ab491f9",
        measurementId: "G-SGPXZS4XET"
    };
    // Initialize Firebase
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    
    
    const auth = firebase.auth();
    const db = firebase.firestore();

    //firebase.analytics();
</script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
```

I am invoking Firebase in code on the image:
[image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.

Answer (score 17):

Error **400** is related to the client-side.

Your code should work correctly so most likely the issue is that you have not yet enabled the **Sign-in method** under Authentication in firebase console.

Comment: thanks, I was wasting time looking for a solution!

Answer (score 12):

Go to the firebase console, navigate to authentication and enable **Email/Password**.
It should work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

yes goto firebase console and enable your google, facebook and email/password fields

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32615846)